# Port Forward on Cisco ASA 5512-X

Tags: cisco, port-forwarding, cisco-asa

i would to improve port forward from an external host to an internal network, on my ASA.

The network and the host are on two different interfaces, the internal network is on the internal interface g0/1 with ip address 192.168.10.0/24 while the outside host is on the outside interface g0/7 with ip address 192.168.17.57.
For my configuration I used port 500 to try to configure port forwarding.

Using the windows function "internet information service" i'm be able to comunicate from the internal subnet to the outside host using "192.168.17.57:500", but i cannot do the same from the outside host to the internal network.

How it's possible to enable it?

This is my configuration:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0

 nameif inside7

 security-level 100

 ip address 192.168.8.1 255.255.255.0


interface GigabitEthernet0/1

 nameif inside1

 security-level 100

 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0


interface GigabitEthernet0/2

 nameif inside2

 security-level 100

 ip address 192.168.12.1 255.255.255.0


interface GigabitEthernet0/3

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

  no ip address


interface GigabitEthernet0/4

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address


interface GigabitEthernet0/5

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address


interface GigabitEthernet0/6

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address


interface GigabitEthernet0/7

 nameif outside7

 security-level 0

ip address 192.168.17.1 255.255.255.0


interface GigabitEthernet0/8

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address


interface Management0/0

 management-only

 nameif management

 security-level 100

ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

ftp mode passive

dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name copying.com

object network RETE1
 range 192.168.10.100 192.168.10.160

object network RETE7
 host 192.168.17.1

object network rete1
 subnet 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0

object service PORT
 service tcp destination eq 500

object network rete17
 host 192.168.17.57

object network RETE17
 subnet 192.168.17.0 255.255.255.0

object service HTTP
 service tcp destination eq www

object network HOST1
 host 192.168.10.102

access-list ACL2 extended permit tcp 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 interface outside7 eq 500

access-list ACL extended permit tcp host 192.168.17.57 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 eq 500

access-list ACL extended permit tcp host 192.168.17.57 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 eq www

access-list ICMP extended permit icmp host 192.168.17.57 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0

pager lines 23

logging asdm informational

mtu inside7 1500

mtu inside1 1500

mtu inside2 1500

mtu outside7 1500

mtu management 1500

no failover

no monitor-interface service-module

icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1

no asdm history enable

arp timeout 14400

no arp permit-nonconnected

nat (inside1,outside7) source static RETE1 interface service PORT HTTP

nat (outside7,inside1) source static rete17 interface service PORT HTTP

access-group ACL2 out interface inside1

access-group ACL in interface outside7

timeout xlate 3:00:00

timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30

timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02

timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00

timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00

timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute

timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00

timeout floating-conn 0:00:00

user-identity default-domain LOCAL

aaa authentication enable console LOCAL

aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL

http server enable

http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 management

no snmp-server location

no snmp-server contact

no service password-recovery

crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite

crypto ca trustpoint _SmartCallHome_ServerCA

 no validation-usage

 crl configure

crypto ca trustpool policy

auto-import

crypto ca certificate chain _SmartCallHome_ServerCA

 certificate ca 6ecc7aa5a7032009b8cebcf4e952d491

class-map inspection_default

 match default-inspection-traffic

class-map ICMP-CLASS

 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!

policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map

 parameters

  message-length maximum client auto

  message-length maximum 512

policy-map ICMP-POLICY

 class ICMP-CLASS

 inspect icmp

policy-map global_policy

 class inspection_default

  inspect dns preset_dns_map

  inspect ftp

 inspect h323 h225

 inspect h323 ras

  inspect rsh

  inspect rtsp

  inspect esmtp

inspect sqlnet

  inspect skinny

  inspect sunrpc

 inspect xdmcp

  inspect sip

 inspect netbios

 inspect tftp

 inspect ip-options


service-policy global_policy global

service-policy ICMP-POLICY interface outside7

no call-home reporting anonymous

call-home
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrea,

I am not sure I understand your question correctly.

You say your internal interface g0/1 with ip address 192.168.10.0/24. Okay that makes sense.

You say your outside host is on the outside interface g0/7 with ip address 192.168.17.57. What do you mean your "outside host"? Is this router not used as a gateway (only for internal traffic routing)?

In any case, the right way to do port redirection is below.

For the destination host (the host that is answering requests received on TCP port 500), you need to make an object. In the code below replace *Private* with the private IP address of the destination host.

```
object network obj_*Private*
host *Private*
```

Then you need to add a NAT statement so that the traffic will be translated from the private IP address to the public IP address. In the following code, you will need to change "inside" to the interface that the private IP address of the destination host is connected to and change "outside" to the interface that the source of the service request is connected to, change *Public* to the public IP address you are going to use for the host, change the SPORT to the port the request is going to be made to and change the DPORT to the port the server is going to accept the request on.

```
nat (inside,outside) static *Public* service tcp SPORT DPORT
```

Your final changes might look like this.

```
object network obj_192.168.10.102
host 192.168.10.102
nat (inside,outside) static 192.168.17.57 service tcp 500 500
```